# How to keep the heading with first paragraph in a html multi column together

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I am receiving content from the backend, which need to render in a multi column layout, and the headline and the first paragraph should always stay together and must not slide in two different columns.

I read some articles here, but they did not match my case and did not solve my issue. The DOM hierarchy is like in the example below.

```
.container {
  column-width: 200px;
}

h2 {
    break-before: auto;
    break-after: avoid-column;
}
h2 + p {
    break-before:avoid;
    color:red;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>My heading1</h2>
    <p>Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon.</p>
    <h2>My heading2</h2>
    <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce.</p>     
</div>
```

Comment: Judging by your example, there can be an arbitrary number of `<p>`s per article ? Ifso then i doubt you can reliably do this in *just* CSS; you'd either have to be able to change the html at the backend, *or* manipulate it as it comes in from the backend. You'll want to have each individual article grouped into a container (a `<div>` or some such).

Comment: I did just now notice you specifically mentioned the **first** paragraph has to stay with the heading, but surely you don't want the other paragraphs to end up somewhere else ? perhaps im picturing a different kind of multicol layout than you...

Comment: Hello Raxi,
you are right, I receive a various amount of paragraphs. And it looks odd, when the headline starts i.e. in column 1 and the text below in column 2. But to not waste too much space, all other paragraphs can flow into the next column. I totally do not understand why my css does not work, since the break properties are explicitly mentioned in multi column layouts https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/